# Selecting rows in a subquery not working when "where in" clause is a dynamic field with replaced JSON brackets/quotes

Tags: mysql, json, subquery

I am trying to write a query to select game names separated by commas in a subquery that are stored in a discount code column in JSON format. The query below currently only returns one result, when I should be expecting multiple game names to follow based on the logic.

```
SELECT
    discount_code, discount_type, percentage_off,
    (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(name) 
        FROM
            games AS g
        WHERE
            g.id IN (
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(dc.game_ids, '[', '' ), ']', ''
                    ), '"', ''
                )
            )
    ) AS game_names
FROM
    discount_codes AS dc
WHERE
    status = 1 AND
    active = 1
ORDER BY
    id
ASC
```

Any idea why the query only returns one result (one game name) from the subquery?

**Edit:**

Example Data:

```
id  name                description
-   -                   -
1   Fun and exciting!   Game description...
2   Game Name           Game description...
```

discount_codes

```
id  discount_code   discount_type       percentage_off  game_ids
-   -               -                   -               -
1   10OFF           single-use          10              ["1"]
2   FREE            ongoing             100             ["1,2"]
```

Comment: Please show us sample data from tables `game` and `discount_coces`, as tabular text, along with the associated expected result.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @GMB I've edited my question and added example data.

Comment: @Nick '10.4.8-MariaDB-1:10.4.8+maria~bionic'

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your query only returns one result is that the return value of your `REPLACE` calls is a string, not a set of values. When MySQL then tries to evaluate that expression, it converts the string to an integer (to match `g.id`) and that results in it returning the first value in the string (e.g. `1,3,5` is converted to `1`), hence you only get one value returned. The best way to implement your desired functionality is to use the inbuilt JSON functions (assuming you are using MySQL 5.7 or later); however, given the nature of your data you still need to remove the double quotes from the values:

```
SELECT
    discount_code, discount_type, percentage_off,
    (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(name) 
        FROM
            game AS g
        WHERE
            JSON_SEARCH(REPLACE(dc.game_ids, '"', ''), 'one', g.id) IS NOT NULL

    ) AS game_names
FROM
    discount_codes AS dc
WHERE
    status = 1 AND
    active = 1
ORDER BY
    id
ASC
```

If you are using a version of MySQL prior to 5.7, you can use `FIND_IN_SET` instead. Note that for `FIND_IN_SET` to work correctly, it's important there are no spaces in the string either, so you need to add another level of `REPLACE` nesting:

```
SELECT
    discount_code, discount_type, percentage_off,
    (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(name) 
        FROM
            game AS g
        WHERE
            FIND_IN_SET(g.id,
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(dc.game_ids, '[', '' ), ']', ''
                    ), '"', ''
                )
            )
    ) AS game_names
FROM
    discount_codes AS dc
WHERE
    status = 1 AND
    active = 1
ORDER BY
    id
ASC
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=8001876e3b1a40c4a362110fa95902d7)

Comment: @hatfieldajoshua I've updated my answer based on the sample data you provided. The `FIND_IN_SET` code remains essentially the same (just with the removal of the code which gets rid of spaces since there aren't any) but the `JSON_SEARCH` code has been changed as it is necessary to remove the double quotes for that to work. I've updated the demo as well.